# Cash balance sign in hedging portfolio

Tags: option-pricing, hedging, cash

Consider a derivative which depends on $n$ assets with price vector $X=(S^1,\dots,S^n)$. The derivative value $V_t$ is given by the function $v(t,S)$, so that the hedge ratios for the hedging portfolio are given by $\partial_iv(t,S)$ for each asset $S^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

**Is there anything we can say in general about the sign of $V_t-\sum_i\partial_iv(t,S)S^i_t$?  If nothing, what additional structure do we need to equip the problem with in order to do so?**

The motivation is that the quantity of interest is usually the value of the cash balance in a hedging portfolio. If its sign was known to be constant throughout, a potential differential between deposit and funding rates would not matter because we would only be paying either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bergman (1995) and Korn (1995) analyse the question in a diffusion setting, with Mercurio (2014) expanding their results.

For example, **Proposition 3** in Bergman (1995) establishes that in a diffusion setting *à la* Black-Scholes where the derivative contract has a terminal payoff function $h$ and is written on some unidimensional asset price $S$, then $v(t,s)-sv_s(t,s)$ has same sign that $h(s)-sh^\prime(s)$ where $v_s$ is the partial derivative w.r.t. to $s$. This is based on a result from Bergman (1994, **equation 24**) which establishes the Black-Scholes $v$ function inherits properties from its boundary function $h$:
$$v(t,S_t)-S_tv_s(t,S_t)=e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}(h(S_T)-S_Th^\prime(S_T)|\mathscr{F}_t)$$
where $h^\prime$ is a generalized function. Mercurio (2014) expands this result to a model with repo financing and collateral.

Assuming the derivative contract depends on some strike $k$, such as an option, it is possible to derive similar results for valuation functions $v$ which are homogeneous of degree 1 in both $s$ and $k$. This is because homogeneity implies that $v(t,s,k)=sv_s(t,s,k)+kv_k(t,s,k)$ by Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions, thus the cash balance is equal to $kv_k(t,s,k)$, then we can use Breeden-Litzenberger formulas which establish a link between the partial derivative $v_k$ and risk-neutral probabilities - for which the sign is known. Merton (1973) establishes conditions under which a derivative price is homogeneous, see e.g. **Theorem 9**.

**References**

Bergman, Yaacov (1994). "General Restrictions on Contingent Claim Prices When Those Solve a PDE", working paper, Hebrew University.

Bergman, Yaacov (1995). "Option Pricing with Differential Rates", *Review of Financial Studies*, Vol. 8, No. 2, pp. 475-500.

Korn, Ralf (1995). "Contingent Claim Valuation in a Market with Different Interest Rates", *Mathematical Methods of Operations Research*, Vol. 42, pp. 255-274.

Mercurio, Fabio (2014). "Differential Rates, Differential Prices", *Risk*, Vol. 27, No. 1, pp. 100-105.

Merton, Robert (1973). "Theory of Rational Option Pricing", *Bell Journal of Economics and Management Science*, Vol. 4, No. 1, pp. 141-183.